# add a datetime element between two other datetime elements

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with a bit low sampling rate. I want to interpolate the NaN values in value column. My problem is the 'ts' column. My samples are not evenly spaced, and I have trouble trying to use timedelta to create the 'ts' value between the samplings.

Example, df.head(4):

```
  'ts'                             'value'
0 PS157 2019-12-17 09:59:20.917000 74.778099 
1 PS157 2019-12-17 00:00:00 NaN 
2 PS157 2019-12-17 09:59:31.918000 176.458374
3 PS157 2019-12-17 00:00:00 NaN
```

I have tried to loop through and do like this:

```
a= PS157['ts'].iloc[i]
b= PS157['ts'].iloc[i+2]
c= (b-a).total_seconds()
d= c/2.0
PS157['ts'].iloc[i+1]= PS157['ts'].iloc[i] + np.timedelta64(d, 's')
```

But this results in:

```
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

I first tried with a 0 value, but then dtypes said 'ts' column was object, not dateime64. So I created a generic 'ts' value for all zeros, and the ran pd.to_datetime. dyptes then say dateime64, but I still get 'could not convert object to NumPy timedelta.

I read somewhere you can't interpolate datetime, so I thought I had to solve it with this workaround, but no luck.

Any good ways to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to just create a "np.timedelta64" on its own, to work out the details. Looks like you need an integer, although it can be an integer of microseconds or smaller. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: Please, post the result of `df.info()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is as simple as passing the correct arguments to the constructor. The docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units specify "The length of the span is the range of a 64-bit integer times the length of the date or unit." You gave it a float where it expected an integer.

Or looking at the source for inspiration, we notice it can take an integer, or a datetime object:

```
class timedelta64(generic):
    def __init__(
        self,
        __value: Union[None, int, _CharLike, dt.timedelta, timedelta64] = ...,
        __format: Union[_CharLike, Tuple[_CharLike, _IntLike]] = ...,
    ) -> None: ...
```

Since your data has something close to milliseconds, I'll go with that:

```
import numpy as np
seconds = (31.918000 - 20.917000) / 2.0
np_diff1 = np.timedelta64(int(seconds * 1000000), 'ms')
```

Here it is with a datetime.timedelta, which does accept a float:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
seconds = (31.918000 - 20.917000) / 2.0
np_diff2 = np.timedelta64(timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```